# Are there download limits for Ubuntu-One published files?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have to share 250 photos in original quality (1GB total) to 40 people.
I know that dropbox public links that use up more than 20 GB/day for Free accounts and 200 GB/day for paid accounts are automatically suspended. ([dropbox help](https://www.dropbox.com/help/45))

Is there a similar limit on Ubuntu-one? I couldn't find it in the [FAQ](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/) page.
Will I run into trouble if I publish it in one compressed file on Ubuntu-One and 40 people download it in a 48 hours timespan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have no problem doing what you describe.

Comment: I didn't encounter any problems sharing the photos using Ubuntu One. It turned out to be reliable for this use-case. thx